# FrameNet and NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have to classify semantic relation of words in sentences.

I am thinking to use FrameNet but I am not sure if NLTK (Python) provides FrameNet along with it.

Anyone know if it possible to use FrameNet with NLTK?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

FrameNet is available with NLTK python but as of now you won'e be able to parse your own text.

But you can use [SEMAFOR](https://github.com/Noahs-ARK/semafor) for that. You need to follow the instructions for the installation and usage.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a FrameNet package for NLTK is coming out soon - https://www.icsi.berkeley.edu/icsi/events/2013/09/framenet-workshop?goback=.gde_131222_member_265383400#!